# Drawing contours in opencv

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision

Am trying to draw contours on an image only when it satisfies below conditions,
1) If the contour's X co-ordinate is less than or equal to 600
2) If the contour's Y co-ordinate is less than or equal to 240
3) If the contour's area is greater than or equal to 900

But i see the output **is not** satisfying these conditions **AT ALL**

(Even added a code to draw a line, it's not showing the line either)

[image]

**Source Code** :

```
import os
import re
import cv2 # opencv library
import numpy as np
from os.path import isfile, join
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


# get file names of the frames
col_frames = os.listdir('persons/')

# sort file names
col_frames.sort(key=lambda f: int(re.sub(r'\D', '', f)))

# empty list to store the frames
col_images=[]

for i in col_frames:
    # read the frames
    img = cv2.imread('persons/'+i)
    # append the frames to the list
    col_images.append(img)

# Taking 66th frame
i = 66

# convert the frames to grayscale
grayA = cv2.cvtColor(col_images[i], cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
grayB = cv2.cvtColor(col_images[i+1], cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)


diff_image = cv2.absdiff(grayB, grayA)
cv2.GaussianBlur(diff_image, (5,5), 0)

# perform image thresholding
ret, thresh = cv2.threshold(diff_image, 30, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)

# apply image dilation
kernel = np.ones((20,20),np.uint8)
dilated = cv2.dilate(thresh,kernel,iterations = 1)

contours,_ = cv2.findContours(dilated, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

valid_cntrs = []

for i,cntr in enumerate(contours):
    x,y,w,h = cv2.boundingRect(cntr)
    print(cv2.contourArea(cntr))
    if ((x <= 600) & (y <= 240)) & (cv2.contourArea(cntr) >= 900):
        valid_cntrs.append(cntr)

#Count of Contours
print('length of contours',len(contours))
# count of discovered contours        
print('length of valid contours',len(valid_cntrs))

dmy = col_images[67].copy()

cv2.line(dmy, (0, 240),(800,240),(100, 255, 255))
cv2.drawContours(dmy, valid_cntrs, -1, (127,200,0), 2)
plt.imshow(dmy)
plt.show()
```

**Output** :

```
49631.0                                                                                                                                                        
65.5                                                                                                                                                           
32.5                                                                                                                                                           
15.0                                                                                                                                                           
654.0                                                                                                                                                          
854.5                                                                                                                                                          
length of contours 6                                                                                                                                           
length of valid contours 1  
<Also the output image above>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to your image and output, it actually seems to be working.
You may not be aware that the x and y coordinates of the bounding boxes are the upper left corner of the rectangle.
If you want to validate the contours based on their middle point, replace the validation part with this code:

```
for i,cntr in enumerate(contours):
    x,y,w,h = cv2.boundingRect(cntr)
    mid_x = x + w / 2.0
    mid_y = y + h / 2.0
    print(cv2.contourArea(cntr))
    if ((mid_x <= 600) & (mid_y <= 240)) & (cv2.contourArea(cntr) >= 900):
        valid_cntrs.append(cntr)
```

To check the right bottom corner of the contour, use instead:

```
for i,cntr in enumerate(contours):
    x,y,w,h = cv2.boundingRect(cntr)
    rb_x = x + w
    rb_y = y + h
    print(cv2.contourArea(cntr))
    if ((rb_x <= 600) & (rb_y <= 240)) & (cv2.contourArea(cntr) >= 900):
        valid_cntrs.append(cntr)
```

Comment: It's not working.. I mean the contours are still the same.
I want the contours to appear only when the y co-ordinate is below 240 in the image.

Comment: You mean you want the shape to be under 240 pixels from the bottom of the image? Because the Y-values ​​of the image also start from the top down

Comment: To be clear,
Imagine a straight horizontal line from 240 point on y axis. 
Now i want only those contours which are above that line but not below.

Comment: Ok, then you should use the bottom right corner of the bounding boxes.
Use the second example that I showed in my answer

Comment: I updated my answer to make it more clear. Use my second suggestion.

Comment: Hey thanks alot, it works! 
And  **cv2.line** function is not drawing line. Can u see what's causing that in the above code.
Also Can you please explain why that contours algorithm works in detail, am actually new to this!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/212629/discussion-between-aditya-nikhil-and-lastairbender).